# What is my error in this matrix / least squares derivation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

I'm doing a simple problem in linear algebra.  It is clear that I have done something wrong, but I honestly can't see what it is.

let,

$y = Ax$, $y_{ls} = Ax_{ls}$ where A is skinny and full rank, and $x_{ls} = (A^T A)^{-1}A^Ty$ is the standard least squares approximation.

Now, I have tried to compute $y^Ty_{ls}$.

$y^Ty_{ls} = y^TAx_{ls} = x^TA^TA(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$

The $A^TA(A^TA)^{-1}$ seems it should cancel to the identity leaving

$x^TA^Ty = y^Ty$.

Clearly this should not be true.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: You mean $x_{ls}=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty_{ls}$?

Comment: I don't think so.  There is an equation $y = Ax$, since A is skinny "some of $y$" is in the nullspace of A.  The least squares solution to this is $x_{ls} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$.  This $x_{ls}$ is the closest (in the least squares sense) approximate solution to $y = Ax$ (since some of y is in the nullspace of A, we need to approximate).  Then the actual value of $y$ produced by the approximation is $y_{ls} = Ax_{ls}$.

That is my understanding.

Comment: If $A$ has a nontrivial nullspace, then $A^TA$ is not invertible.

Comment: A is known to be full rank, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this: your problem is overdetermined and there is no solution vector $x$ such that
$$
\mathbf{A}x - b = 0.
$$
Instead of asking for an exact solution, we relax requirements and ask for the best solution. Picking the $2-$norm, the best solution is 
$$
x_{LS} = \left\{ x\in\mathbb{C}^{n} \colon \lVert \mathbf{A} x_{LS} - b \rVert_{2}^{2} \text{ is minimized} \right\}.
$$

Summary: 
$$
\mathbf{A} x_{LS} \ne b,
$$
instead $\mathbf{A}x_{LS}$ is as close as possible to $b$ as measured in the $2-$norm.